# Disable Hazelcast instance while running JUnit test with ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast, junit5

I have such JUnit 5 test and becuase of test speed I need to disable creating Hazelcast instances while running test. Is there some way how to disable Hazelcast for one particular test?

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class MemoryTradeCommunicatorTest {
// test cases....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three main ways to approach your problem. I'll assume you just need to disable Hazelcast and that you're using Spring Boot though you don't mention it explicitly.

1. As Dmitrii mentions, you can mock the bean that provides the Hazelcast instance. Be aware that you'll probably need to split your configuration into multiple fragments so that you can import the beans required in your tests.
2. You can use Spring profiles. You'd need to create a `test` profile and create a mock Hazelcast instance inside it. The implementation depends a lot on how you create the real Hazelcast instance (Spring Boot or manually).
3. Spring Boot creates the Hazelcast instance because of auto-configuration classes. You can prevent this behavior by [excluding specific classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration). In your case, you'd launch your tests with `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastAutoConfiguration`

Comment: Hazelcast instance is created automatically by Spring Boot, because of it I'm afraid I can't control the creation by processing with Spring Bean as you mentioned. Is there any way how to solve this situation?

Comment: I tried it today, 3rd option works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Import` for loading only required beans and mock your Hazelcast bean something like that:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(value = {MemoryTradeCommunicator.class})

@MockBean
private CacheManager cacheManager;

class MemoryTradeCommunicatorTest {
// test cases....
}
```

Where CacheManager is your Hazelcast realization. Also, don't forget to declare your other needed bean into `@Import`